# Index an inherited ProductTemplate field on ProductProduct

Tags: sql, postgresql, odoo

I've added a field to product.template, `source_id`, via:

```
class ProductTemplate(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'

    source_id = fields.Integer('Original Source ID', help="The original source ID", index=True, required=False)
```

Right now my SQL DELETE queries on product.product are taking forever because `source_id` isn't an actual indexable field on product.product.

What I would like to do is inherit this same field on product.product, so that I can search product.product by `source_id` and perform large SQL DELETE queries on product.product.

Any suggestions for how to approach this?

An alternative solution would be to figure out a way to destroy dependent product.product records when DELETE is run on product.template. I'm not sure how to do this in Odoo/Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below code:

```
class ProductProduct(models.Model):
_inherit = 'product.product'

source_id = fields.Integer('Original Source ID',related='product_tmpl_id.source_id', help="The original source ID")
```